# SSIS Package Optimization for thousands of excel files and archival on the basis of business logic

Tags: sql-server, ssis, ssis-2012

I have developed a scenario where ssis package will retrieve the excel file name using foreach loop and search whether that file name is part of business logic.
If it isn't I need to archive that, I have done that using File system task.Now the problem here is, for each loop is taking approximately 5 seconds for each file.Now there are thousands of fies in the folder how can i optimize the code to run faster?

I have developed SSIS package containing a procedure will run and then  inside foreachloop there is execute sql task to identify whether that filename is part of business logic if no then i am passing flag as 0 and if yes flag as 1.And then I used file system task to move the file to the archive folder.

Comment: What is the logic that determines whether it is part of business logic? And how do you get the list of files. It sounds like that you can turn your solution into a dataflow where every file is processed in parallel.

Comment: There are 2 conditions first there is account id in file let's say acc*.xlsx is what the file name starts with. So here condition is for every acc files there will be only file with same account id for eg acc_21_YYMMDd,acc_22_YYMMDD and so on..and another condition is files execution date  in the main folder should not be greater than 6 months. If both the condition fails there is a need for achival..

Comment: You could create a scripting component in a dataflow as a source where you can do the checks and in next one you can do the archival. You can also ask yourself the question whether it is not easier just to create a small c# console program and schedule that one.